# How to get the referrer pathname outside of my website

Tags: javascript

I tried to get the referrer using `document.referrer` and I tried to get the referrer patname using this:

```
document.referrer.replace(/^[^:]+:\/\/[^/]+/, '').replace(/#.*/, '').replace(/\?.*/, '');
```

but I found out that `document.referrer` can only get the pathname referrer inside your own website.

Suppose that my website is https://example.com . And I tried to alert the referrer like this:

```
alert(document.referrer);
```

If the visitor came from https://google.com/testing , document.referrer will only show the https://google.com and not the pathname of it.

> document.referrer can only get the pathname referrer inside your own website

**Question**: how to get the referrer with pathname that comes from outside of my website? Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Comment: "document.referrer can only get the pathname referrer inside your own website" where did you read that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: The referer value is controlled by the source site; there's nothing your page can do about what another site tells the browser to do.

Comment: some resources about HTTP Referer headers (not much to do with javascript): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Comment: HI, proof that "document.referrer can only get the pathname referrer inside your own website". please check my website, i wrote this: alert(document.referrer); on there:  

https://legendsfreenetph.com/folder/

Comment: @GrafiCode
done, sorry

Comment: Your assertion is not true. A source website *can* request that the complete origin path be preserved, but by default it is not, and a source website can request that no referer header is sent at all. Again, there is nothing you can do about that from your own site.

Comment: instead of showing that the referrer is https://legendsfreenetph.com/folder/  it only shows https://legendsfreenetph.com/

Comment: it also depends on what browser you're using. have a look at this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default `strict-origin-when-cross-origin offers more privacy. With this policy, only the origin is sent in the Referer header of cross-origin requests.

This prevents leaks of private data that may be accessible from other parts of the full URL such as the path and query string.` NOTE: `This means that if no policy is set for your website, Chrome will use strict-origin-when-cross-origin by default.`

Comment: so there is no solution for this? Thanks

Comment: as Pointy already stated, you can do nothing about it, unless you own the external domain and configure its HTTP referrer policy to allow cross-origin

Comment: Hi, i own the external domain., how to configure its HTTP referrer policy to allow cross-origin ?

Comment: This doesnot work
<meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url">
<a href="https://phsensei.com" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url">Click mE</a>

Comment: you might be clashing with server-side directives, `.htacces` file for instance might contain different statements